# 'Invalid GeoJSON geometry' error while exporting an array as CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, array

My variable `array1` is a list of objects. I am trying to export this list as a table in Excel to do work on that. However, the error I am getting is this:

```
Line 184: Invalid GeoJSON geometry: {"total_pixels":{"yg":{"ea":{"args":[{"description":"","type":"Dictionary","name":"dictionary","default":null},{"description":"","type":"String","name":"key","default":null},{"description":"","type":"Object","name":"defaultValue","default":null,"optional":true}],"description":"Extracts a named value from a dictionary.  If the dictionary does not contain the given key, then defaultValue is returned, unless it is null."...
```

The error is huge. It goes on for 200k words. I had to cut short the error wording. Like it is a loop problem or something.

My code before is just to find the values of total_pixels, ... and other variables.

```
var ids = (agr_poly.aggregate_array("pointid"));
print(ids)

var array1 = [];

for (var i=0; i<55; i++)
{
  var grid= agr_poly.filter(ee.Filter.eq("pointid", ids.get(i)))
  
  var masking_collection2 = masking_collection.clip(grid)//map(clippolygon)
  // print(masking_collection2, 'clipped_landsat',i)
  // Map.addLayer(masking_collection2, {}, 'clipped_landsat',i)
  // print(grid.first())
  // Map.addLayer(grid, {}, "tester")
 
  var first = ee.Array([1]);
  
  var total_pixels = (masking_collection2.select('snowmask').reduceRegion
  ({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: grid
  }));
  
  var classified = masking_collection2.select('snowmask');

  var onlyopenfor = classified.updateMask(
  classified.eq(1) )
  
   var total_yes_snow = (onlyopenfor.reduceRegion
  ({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: grid
  }));
  
  var onlyopenforno = classified.updateMask(
  classified.eq(0) )
  
   var total_no_snow = (onlyopenforno.reduceRegion
  ({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: grid
  }));

  var tp = total_pixels.get('snowmask');
  var yp = total_yes_snow.get('snowmask');
  var np = total_no_snow.get('snowmask');

  var resulting_array ={'total_pixels': tp,'total_yes_snow': yp, 'total_no_snow': np, 'id': ids.get(i)}; 

  array1.push(resulting_array);
}

print('Final Array', array1)

var array2 = ee.FeatureCollection(array1
  .map(function (dict) {
    return ee.Feature(dict);
  })
);

Export.table.toDrive(array2);
```

What is this error?

Comment: `array1` doesn't follow [GeoJSON specification](https://geojson.org). It is just a JSON object, not GeoJSON. This is why you get the error.

Comment: but so how do i fix it then? I have to put in coordinates for it to convert it to GeoJSON. But what i am working with is just an array of values. I dont have any geolocated data for those values..?

Comment: Ok. `resulting_array` is a multi-nested dictionary. Can you show us exactly how you want the excel table to look like?

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the error is that you are passing a dictionary to the first parameter of the `Feature` constructor. However, the first parameter has to be geometry and the second parameter has to be dictionary.

You need to specify the feature's geometry in `Feature` constructor. Since you don't need a geometry, you can set to `null` to export to Excel.

In `map` function, change

```
return ee.Feature(dict);
```

to

```
return ee.Feature(null, dict);
```

This solves the `Invalid GeoJSON geometry` error. But you need to reorganize `tp`, `yp`, `np` not to get other errors. Beacuse `resulting_array` is a multi-nested dictionary. It doesn't follow GeoJSON `property` specifications.

Comment: I didn't test it. I am not sure whether it works or not.